# How to call a function that is located in another class in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, swift3

I try to make the Label in iOS app to show `"asdf"`  in label using 2 view controller.

I try to run `testA()` function but it shows out an error: `ViewController.swift:15:9: Use of unresolved identifier 'testA'`

#### My initial code:

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        testA()
    } 
}
```

In another controller (TestViewController):

```
import UIKit

class TestViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

    func testA() {
        testLabel.text = "asdf"
    }

}
```

and my Main.storyboard is linked to TestViewController class

I did a little bit search on google and I came to try out inheritance and It did not shows the error, but the function was not called.

### I try to use Inheritance method:

In View Controller (ViewController.swift):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: TestViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        testA()
    }
}
```

The error was resolved, but the label did not change to `asdf`

How do I make my `ViewController.swift` able to call the function `testA()` that is located in another controller `TestViewController.swift` ?

Comment: Seems like you are very new to Swift and programming in general. I recommend taking Object Oriented tutorials/classes before starting ios development.

Answer (score 4):

You can create an object of that class and you can call the function as below.

```
let testVC = TestViewController()
```

Now call the function using the object

```
testVC.testA()
```

Or better approach is to create a `class func` if you want to call it from many places and it's independent of the object.

```
class Helper {
    class func testFunction() {
      // Do something
    }
}
```

In above scenario, you don't have to create the object as it's a class method so call it like below.

```
Helper.testFunction()
```

Comment: getting error on this: Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

Answer (score 2):

You can use NSNotification or ou can use delegate if load the second view after the first.

Comment: Although this may help the OP it should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: this NSNotification solution helps many the OP if they don't can save a reference to the ViewA.

Answer (score 1):

public the `testA()` function and call the

```
TestViewController.testA()
```

in the `override func viewDidLoad()`of `ViewController`
import TestViewController at first.

Comment: To call a method like this you need to declare the method that you are calling a class or static method.